# Call a function after SetTimeout function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, settimeout

I have this code that make an image animation, but I want to call the function `AnotherAction()` when the animation is finished through the call `clearTimeout(gLoop);`

```
var Animate = function(){  
    Clear();  
    MoveDown();  
    gLoop = setTimeout(Animate,40);  
}

var MoveDown = function(){  
    // animation code  
    if(velocity==0){  
        clearTimeout(gLoop);  
        AnotherAction();  //Here is not working  
    }  
}
```

Where I supposed to make the call to `AnotherAction()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're clearing the timeout **before** you're setting it the next time.  `MoveDown` is clearing the timeout, but as soon as control switches back to Animate, you're setting it again.

Try something like this:

```
var Animate = function(){  
    Clear();  
    if (MoveDown())
        gLoop = setTimeout(Animate,40);  
}

var MoveDown = function(){  
    // animation code  
    if(velocity==0){  
        AnotherAction();  //Here is not working  
        return false;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, why would `clearTimeout()` before another function call not allow that function to be called?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - it would allow the other function to be called, but I assume the problem is that the original setTimeout, that calls Animate, is still being fired, which is screwing up his results.

Comment: Shouldn't `MoveDown` also `return true` if the `if` block doesn't run?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - no doubt.  `Internet high five` :-)